# Как просканировать диапазон IP адресов на наличие определённого открытого порта с помощью nmap?

Tags: сеть, ip, порт, сканирование

Используя nmap, я столкнулся с такой проблемой: когда я сканирую диапазон IP-адресов на наличие определённого открытого порта с помощью nmap, мне выводится много информации: закрытые, открытые и фильтрующиеся порты. Информация о закрытых и фильтрующихся портах мне абсолютно не нужна, мне нужно, чтобы выводились только открытые порты и IP-адрес, где этот порт открыт. Напишите пожалуйста, какую команду мне для этого использовать. Было бы идеально, если бы информация выводилась в таком виде, если это возможно:
**Discovered open port 12345/tcp on 94.75.2.5** (например)
**Discovered open port 12345/tcp on 94.75.2.10** (например)
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте grep, выведет строки, начинающиеся с 'Discovered'

```
nmap 10.0.0.0/24  -Pn -p 22  -v | grep 'Discovered'
```

Comment: Я правильно понял, это способ для Линукса? А возможно ли подобное сделать в Windows, используя Zenmap GUI?

Comment: да, для linux. для windows cmd замените grep на findstr. GUI не пользуюсь. Там нет консоли встроенной?

Comment: В GUI строка для ввода команды, и окно вывода. Благодарю за помощь